# ACF loop and php formatting

Tags: php, loop, advanced-custom-fields, formatting

The following php will loop through each page and then output **ALL** of the ACF custom fields sequentially. What I need help formatting is a conditional statement that places all `$fields`, except `$field_name` containing 'title', in their own container.

```
$pages = get_pages( array('sort_column' => 'menu_order')); 
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $fields = get_fields($page_data);
    if( $fields )
    {

      foreach( $fields as $field_name => $value )
      {

       $field = get_field_object($field_name, false, array('load_value' => false));

       // if(strpos($field_name,"title") !== false ){
       // /*this field has name containing title*/
       // }

       echo '<div class='.$field_name.'>';
       echo $value;
       echo '</div>';

      }
    }

}
```

So final HTML should look like:

```
<div class="the_title">TITLE</div>
  <div class="container">
     <div class="1">1</div>
     <div class="2">2</div>
     <div class="3">3</div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What is the name of the exact name of the key storing your title? Or are they programmaticaly generated into something like `title_0097` or similar?

Comment: @MichaelJames I can explicitly define them. i.e. the could all be "the_title".

Comment: @sweeds with `strpos($field_name, 'title') !== FALSE` you're checking if the  string `"title"` exists anywhere within `$field_name`. with `strpos($field_name, 'title') === 0`  you're checking if `"title"` is positioned at the very beginning of `$field_name`. If you're checking just `strpos($field_name, 'title')` you can't know if it's one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can be explicetly defined as `the_title`, then this should work for you:

```
$pages = get_pages(array ('sort_column' => 'menu_order')); 

foreach ($pages as $page_data) { 
    $fields = get_fields($page_data); 
    if( $fields ) {
        echo '<div class="the_title">' .$fields['the_title'] . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="container">';
        foreach( $fields as $field_name => $value ) { 
            $field = get_field_object($field_name, false, array('load_value' => false)); 

            if($field_name != 'the_title' ){  /*this field does not have key of 'the_title'*/
                echo '<div class='.$field_name.'>';
                    echo $value; 
                echo '</div>'; 
              }

         }
        echo '</div>'; 

    } 
}
```

Apologies if there are any erroneous gaps. My phone likes to drop in spaces when I'm writing code for some reasons.

any questions,  ask away.